# Which kubernetes version is supported in docker version 18.09

Tags: docker, kubernetes, version

I am using `Raspberry pi` for `kubernetes` cluster setup. I was using below docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:30:52 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
 Version:          18.06.1-ce
 API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:       go1.10.3
 Git commit:       e68fc7a
 Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:26:37 2018
 OS/Arch:          linux/arm
 Experimental:     false
```

Looks like now the docker version latest is `18.09.0` and the latest `kubernetes` version is not supporting this docker version. I have even tried installing some older version of kube like `1.9.7` or `1.9.6` but while initiating the `kubeadm init`,  I am getting the below error:

```
[ERROR SystemVerification]: unsupported docker version: 18.09.0
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

Which version should I specify for `kubernetes` and `docker` to run properly. Also how can we specify version while insatlling docker. I normally use below command to install docker:

```
curl -sSL get.docker.com | sh
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Kubernetes there is nothing like *supported*. Instead of it they use *validated* - it means that all features were tested and validated with some Docker version.

And validated Docker versions are still the same from Kubernetes version 1.8 until 1.11: **Docker 1.11.2 to 1.13.1 and 17.03.x**. See here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.8.md#external-dependencies
and here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.11.md#external-dependencies

Starting from Kubernetes version 1.12 **Docker 17.06, 17.09 and 18.06** started to be also validated. See here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.12.md#external-dependencies

As I know final version of Docker 18.09 was released 4 days ago so here we cannot expect this version to be validated in Kubernetes now.

**Update (9.4.2019):** Docker 18.09 is validated against newly released Kubernetes 1.14: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.14.md#external-dependencies

---

You can specify exact Docker version for the *get.docker.com* script by `VERSION` variable:

```
export VERSION=18.03 && curl -sSL get.docker.com | sh
```

Comment: Where should I put this variable definition so that get.docker.script could see it?

Comment: You can use that "one line" command or explicitly run `export VERSION=18.06` and then in the second step `curl -sSL get.docker.com | sh`. It is an environment variable.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I "fixed" mine:

```
$ sudo kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=SystemVerification
...
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: unsupported docker version: 18.09.0
```

Here's what I saw when "preflight errors" were ***not*** ignored:

```
$ sudo kubeadm init
...
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR SystemVerification]: unsupported docker version: 18.09.0
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

Here's the version of `kubeadm` I used:

```
$ kubeadm version --output json
{
  "clientVersion": {
    "major": "1",
    "minor": "12",
    "gitVersion": "v1.12.2",
    "gitCommit": "17c77c7898218073f14c8d573582e8d2313dc740",
    "gitTreeState": "clean",
    "buildDate": "2018-10-24T06:51:33Z",
    "goVersion": "go1.10.4",
    "compiler": "gc",
    "platform": "linux/amd64"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above, the message is more of a warning that not all features were tested against that specific Docker release. On your own risk, you can try to temporarily ignore those errors by using the `--ignore-preflight-errors` flag. Eg :
`kubedam init --ignore-preflight-errors all`

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem as:

> > kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=SystemVerification

Comment: stuck at $ sudo kubeadm join 127.0.0.1:6443  --token XXXr42jr     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:bad5XXXX   -->> error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR IsDockerSystemdCheck]: cannot execute 'docker info': exit status 125
        [ERROR SystemVerification]: failed executing "docker info --format '{{json .}}'"\noutput: flag provided but not defined: --format
See 'docker info --help'.
\nerror: exit status 125
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`

Comment: --ignore-preflight-errors=SystemVerification --ignore-preflight-errors=IsDockerSystemdCheck